# Need to add UID for the data set in the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba7

I have a dataset and that have the values in B and C columns. I need to add the UID for every instances of data present in the B column. Example.

The column A should give me the UID for data set based on the data present in the column B.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvOke.png]

I have tried many formulas but not seem to be relevant for what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula. Put the formula in `A2` cell then drag and down.

```
="TT" & COUNTA($B$2:$B2)
```

[image]